# UIPageViewController with a Table View, inside an UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I want to replicate this sort of UX, like in the product hunt app

I want a few scroll pages inside a tableview

I tried to replicate creating a tableview with some static cell and a cell with a container view inside that is referred to a page controller, but I have a lot of problems adjusting frames

Do you have some advices or more straightforward methods to replicate this ux?

[Imagur Link to the Gif of the UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhLuy.jpg)

Comment: use scrollview or collectioview in the tableviewcell

Comment: the pages are different in sizes, the first can be a 45 row tableview, the second only a label, how can i adapt the size of the main table view cell? 

I'm trying to using a delegate to change the cell height based on the page height but I'm having some frame sizes  errors

Comment: Have you found any elegant way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect with the help of these two libraries.

**For Parralax TableView header :**

https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader

**For horizontal scroll effect:**

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/instagram-feed-view